# Офонарение — откуда взялось слово?

Tags: сленг

"Ты что, офонарел?!" — восклицаем мы, когда видим, что оппонент делает или говорит или делает что-то неожиданно неприятное или странное. А при чем тут, собственно, фонарь?

Answer (score 5):

Я думаю, что выражение "офонареть" происходит от ситуации, когда подвыпивший гражданин идет из кабака домой и врезается в сильно покосившийся фонарный столб. Ну , или гражданин сильный закос произведет. Шишка на лбу или "фонарь" под глазом обеспечены надолго.

[Байка о фонарях](http://forum.fonarevka.ru/showthread.php?t=6664) (я в нее не верю))) : " В масло стали добавлять спирт
для яркости и долготы горения. Однако
по вполне понятным причинам это
новшество не прижилось. Отсюда как
раз и пошло выражение "офонареть".
Какой же выпивоха мог пройти мимо
очередного фонаря?! Так что после
нескольких "остановок" человек
хорошенько напивался, и в народе
звали его офонаревшим. Когда
генерал-губернатором Москвы был
знаменитый и страшный Закревский,
брандмайор Беринг, заведовавший
городскими фонарями, приказал
добавлять в вожделенный фонарный
спирт отвратительную пахучую
жидкость, чтобы отбить у любителей
выпить всякое желание побаловаться
бесплатным «угощением». Приготовив
это пойло, он позвал самого заядлого
пропойцу-фонарщика, приказал ему
залпом осушить весь стакан и
осведомился: «Ну, как?» «Ничего, ваше
превосходительство! Крепенько, а так
пить можно», — услышал он в ответ от
крайне довольного солдата" Байка знатная, но явно выдуманная.

Answer (score 4):

Прочитал интересную версию, что слово офонарел пришло из языка шахтёров. Дело в том, что раньше для освещения они пользовались подсвечником окружённым специальной решёткой.  Подсвечник располагался в непосредственной близости от паха, что могло способствовать переносу на фонарь известного матерного синонима. По той же причине близости появилось и выражение "по барабану".